# Multiple Docker containers using the same image with Spring Boot Profiles & Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, gradle, docker-compose

I'm trying to run multiple instances of an API from the same image and same Gradle script. As you can see below in my docker-compose file, I have api-participant, and would like to create api-participant2, 3, 4 etc, because they each need their independent, custom applications, DB, frontend, etc.

The first container will run successfully, but any subsequent containers will give me the following error:

```
| > Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().

| > Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionScopeServices.createFileSnapshotter().
```

Any help or references much appreciated!

```
api-participant:
    build:
      context: ./api-participant
    command: -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs="-Xmx2g -Xdebug" bootRun #--debug-jvm
    ports:
      - "3007:8080"
      - "3008:8181"
      - "5006:5005"
    links:
      - mongo-participant
      - member0
      - ipfs
    volumes:
      - ./api-participant:/opt/app
      - ~/.m2/repository:/root/.m2/repository/
      - ./ethereum/app/truffle/contracts:/opt/app/src/main/solidity
      - ./ethereum/keys:/opt/blockchain/keys
    environment:
      - LOG_LEVEL=debug
      - CORS_WHITELIST=http://localhost:3011
```

Comment: You're mapping to the same ports on the host machine (3007, 3008 and 5006). This won't work, they are already blocked by the first container running.

Comment: ports:
      - "3027:8080"
      - "3028:8181"
      - "5028:5005"


These are my ports for participant2